# Update modal value with the server response data in React-Semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, state, semantic-ui, prop

I have a multiple hyperlinks with some ID. when the link is clicked I have to show a loading symbol in modal and I have to make a axios call. Once the api returns the data then I have to update the result in that same modal.

below is my code

```
class App extends React.Component {
   renderContent() {
     return (
       // This data generated using map function
       <Modal trigger={<a onClick={() => this.generateAppJson("1") }>Generate App JSON</a> } basic size='small'>
         <Header icon='spinner loading' content='Get the name' />
         <Modal.Content>
           <p>Loading...</p> {/* Here I have to update the content that received form  generateAppJson() function*/}
         </Modal.Content>
       </Modal>

       <Modal trigger={<a onClick={() => this.generateAppJson("2") }>Generate App JSON</a> } basic size='small'>
         <Header icon='spinner loading' content='Get the name' />
         <Modal.Content>
           <p>Loading...</p> {/* Here I have to update the content that received form  generateAppJson() function*/}
         </Modal.Content>
       </Modal>
     )
   }

  generateAppJson(id) {
    console.log(id)
    // Here I'll make axios call and I have to update the result in the same model
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Segment>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </Segment>
    );
  }
}
```

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/pm6knmr37j

Currently, When I click the link modal is opening and showing the loading text. But How do I update the modal content once the data is retrieved from the api in `generateAppJson()`

Also, I want only one Modal that should call for all the hyperlinks. Currently, How Do i move out from the loop and call when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the axios return data to component state which will automatically rerender you app.

So firstly you will need to update the component state when your axios call has returned:

```
  async generateAppJson(id) {
    const results = await axios.post(someurl, id);
    // this line will cause a rerender
    this.setState({results})
  }
```

Then you'll need to initialise the state in your component:

```
class App  extends React.Component {
   state = { results: [] }
```

Then you'll need to check the state in your render function:

```
<Modal.Content>
    { !this.state.results.length && <p>Loading...</p>}
    { this.state.results.length &&
        this.state.results.map(result => <someothercomponent key={result} /> )
    }
</Modal.Content>
```